# Trying to print results on terminal Using Selenium on Mac OS VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to Python and Selenium

The Code I am trying to run was supposed to print the amazon results in the terminal on the terminal :

the first code is. :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/Python Projects/Selenium Automation /Web Scraping (1)/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
search.send_keys("usb c to hdmi")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "s-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row"))
    )
    print(main.text)
except:
    driver.quit()



driver.quit()
```

This opens everything correctly but isn't printing the results onto the terminal

The second code i tired :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/Python Projects/Selenium Automation /Web Scrapping (1)/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
search.send_keys("usb c to hdmi")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "s-main-slot s-result-list s-search-results sg-row"))
    )
    
except:
    driver.quit()

print(main.text)

driver.quit()
```

but with the second code, it keeps coming up with this error?

```
print(main.text)
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure you are getting error in try/except. you should add error exception class in expect so you don't want to deal with this kind of situations. so now you need to do is comment or remove try except or run your code without try except and paste the exception you get.

Comment: you can verify that you are getting error in try/except via updated this `except: driver.quit()` to this `except: print("Error") driver.quit()` keep in mind about indentation.

Comment: i don't know if its in try/except. Ive changed it to your code and it still says main isnt defined

Comment: did you get "error' str printed in terminal/cmd? you should show your new output to me.

Comment: (1)/amazon_search.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fuadhafiz/Documents/Python Projects/Selenium Automation /Web Scrapping (1)/amazon_search.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(main)
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
fuadhafiz@Fuads-iMac Web Scrapping (1) %

Comment: give me a moment.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem in your try/except & your css selector and your code structure.

You need try this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")

search = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
search.send_keys("usb c to hdmi")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".s-main-slot")))
    print(main.text)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout")

driver.quit()
```

Comment: It works! 

However, in the problems tab in VS Code, it says Undefined variable 'TimeoutException'

Answer (score 0):

from what it seems you made no variable called "main.txt" and thats why it isnt printing. if you did make one the reason it isnt working is also probably because you cant have periods in the variable name either.

Comment: Ok ive changed it to print(main) but it now says main isnt defined ?